# Facebook Open Graph get shares - reload cache issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

i'v implemented a sharing counter with Facebook Open Graph Shares, here the code:

```
        <script>
          function GetShareTargetCMS(){
            var token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
             $.ajax({
               url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/',
                 dataType: 'jsonp',
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 data: {access_token: token, id: "http://url-to-share", scrape:true  },
                 success: function(data){
                   console.log(data.share);
                     if(typeof data.share != 'undefined'){
                       $('.results_share').empty().html('<span>'+data.share.share_count+'</span>');
                     }else{
                       $('.results_share').empty().html('<span>0</span>');
                     }//else
                 }//success
             });
          }//GetShareTargetCMS
          //Get Condivisioni
          $(document).ready(function() {
              GetShareTargetCMS();
           });
           //Get Condivisioni


    //Share trigger dialog
    document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
              FB.ui({
                method: 'share',
                mobile_iframe: true,
                href: "http://url-to-share",
              }, function(response){ GetShareTargetCMS(); });
            }

</script>
```

By default the functions called in document ready print the share counter of the current page inside a dive. If users click .shareBtn i open a share dialog. When sharing is success i re-call the sharing function to reload and update the share count. I don't kwnow the reasons but the counter not refreshing. the only way to refresh the counter is reload the page. Any advice?

I tried:

- Using GET instead POST
- Tried to omit the "scrape: true" in data param.
- Using the code "directly" without a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a timeout before refreshing your share count

```
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
          FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            mobile_iframe: true,
            href: "http://url-to-share",
      }, function(){setTimeout(function(){GetShareTargetCMS()},1000) });
}
```